# What are standards for sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName & sonar.projectVersion?

Tags: sonarqube

I like to know if there are any standards for sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName & sonar.projectVersion.

I am working on git environment and will require sonar analysis for different git branches of the same git repository.

Answer (score 7):

All this is described on ["Analysis Parameters" documentation page](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters/):

> sonar.projectKey   => The project key that is unique for each project.
> Allowed characters are: letters, numbers, '-', '_', '.' and ':', with
> at least one non-digit.
>
> sonar.projectName => Name of the project that will be displayed on the
> web interface.
>
> sonar.projectVersion   => The project version.

`sonar.projectKey` and `sonar.projectName` will be fixed, and `sonar.projectVersion` will probably be different on the different git branches.

Also, for managing branches, you will have to pass the extra `sonar.branch` property when launching the analysis. For instance (let's say that master is the main dev branch):

- on your master branch, you will just run:

  `sonar-scanner`
- on your "x.y" branch, you will run:

  `sonar-scanner -Dsonar.branch=x.y`

Comment: Should the sonar.projectVersion to include git-commit id ?

You mentioned that **sonar.projectVersion will have to be different on the different git branches**. If you can give an example that will be great.

Comment: Not necessarily. What I wanted to say is that there are chances that each branch represents a different version of your code, so "sonar.projectVersion" should reflect this.

Comment: Recommend against `:` in the projectKey since it gets URL-encoded (mangled) --so we've switched to `_` to delimit Git repo_org.

Comment: Should we rerun the test on the other branch if we want to cover two branches ?